# Pygame side scroller how to repeat an event with a certain interval?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making an side-scroller arcade game where you control a rocket and have to avoid waves of asteroids coming from the right to the left. The problem I have is that the wave only comes one time. My loop to do another wave does not work. Help is very much appreciated. I have added my code below:

```
#Make a first "game" which is actually the menu
res = (1000,800)
screen = pg.display.set_mode(res)
pg.display.set_caption('Rocket game')
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
backgroundmenu = pg.image.load("menuscreen.jpg")

pg.init()

pg.mixer.music.load('gamesound.mp3')
pg.mixer.music.set_endevent(pg.constants.USEREVENT)
pg.mixer.music.play()

running1 = True
while running1:
    pg.event.pump()
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_1]:
        running1 = False
        running2 = True
    elif keys[pg.K_2]:
        running1 = False
        running2 = False
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running1 = False
    screen.blit(backgroundmenu,(0,0))
    pg.display.flip()
pg.quit()

pg.init()
#Setup screen and define colors
res = (1000,800)
screen = pg.display.set_mode(res)
pg.display.set_caption('Rocket game')
#pg.image.load("space.jpg")
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
background1 = pg.image.load("space.jpg").convert()
background2 = pg.image.load("space.jpg").convert()
background3 = pg.image.load("space.jpg").convert()
#screen.blit(background1,(0,0))
x_back = 0
screenwidth = 1000
#Initialize variables and clock
vx = 0
vy = 0
x = 200
y = 600
t0 = 0.001*pg.time.get_ticks()
maxdt = 0.5

#Load rocket and asteroids
rocketgif = pg.image.load("rocket.gif")
rocketimg = pg.transform.scale(rocketgif, (100,100))

asteroidgif = pg.image.load("Asteroid.gif")
asteroidimg = pg.transform.scale(asteroidgif, (75,75))


#Load music
pg.mixer.music.load('gamesound.mp3')
pg.mixer.music.set_endevent(pg.constants.USEREVENT)
pg.mixer.music.play()

#clock = pg.time.Clock()



#Generate random asteroids at right of the screen (x =999) and at a random y position (between 0 and 800)
Nasteroid = 4
x_ast = 999
dx = 5
i = 0
asteroidpos_y= []
while i<Nasteroid:
    y = randint(0,800)
    asteroidpos_y.append(y)
    i = i + 1

#Start game loop
running2 = True
while running2:

    t = 0.001*pg.time.get_ticks()
    dt = min(t-t0,maxdt)



    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:                                   #Quit using red cross button
            running2  = False
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
            running2 = False                                            #Quit using key combination



        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:                                 #Make user control rocket movement
                                                                       #and stop if key is released.
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                vx = -8
            elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                vx = 8
            elif event.key == pg.K_UP:
                vy = -8
            elif event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                vy = 8


        elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:

            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                vx = 0
            elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                vx = 0
            elif event.key == pg.K_UP:
                vy = 0
            elif event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                vy = 0
        elif event.type == pg.constants.USEREVENT:

            pg.mixer.music.load("gamesound.mp3")
            pg.mixer.music.play()

    #Make the screen scroll behind the rocket to make it "move" (3x the same background behind eachother)
    screen.blit(background1,(x_back,0))
    screen.blit(background2,(x_back - screenwidth,0))
    screen.blit(background3,(x_back - (2*screenwidth),0))
    x_back = x_back - 1
    if x_back == screenwidth:
        x_back = 0
    i = 0
    pg.event.pump()     #Flush event queue

    #Update position of the rocket
    x = x + vx
    y = y + vy
    """if x <= 0 or x >=100:
        running2 = False
    if y <= 0 or y >=800:
        running2 = False"""
    #Calculate distance between rocket and asteroid
    sx = abs(x - x_ast)
    sy = abs(y - asteroidpos_y[i-1])
    sxy = sqrt(sx**2 + sy**2)

    #Wave of asteroids
    while i<Nasteroid:
        x_ast -= dx
        y = y
        screen.blit(asteroidimg,(x_ast,asteroidpos_y[i-1]))
        i = i + 1

    #Check if rocket is in touching distance of an asteroid. If hit, play explosion sound and exit game
    if sx <= 75 and sy <= 75 or sxy <= 75:
        pg.mixer.music.load('explosion.mp3')
        pg.mixer.music.set_endevent(pg.constants.USEREVENT)
        pg.mixer.music.play()

        time.sleep(1)

        running2 = False
    else:
        while i<Nasteroid:
            y = randint(0,800)
            asteroidpos_y.append(y)
            i = i + 1
            while i<Nasteroid:
                x_ast -= dx
                y = y
                screen.blit(asteroidimg,(x_ast,asteroidpos_y[i-1]))
                i = i + 1


    pg.event.pump()
    screen.blit(rocketimg,(x,y))
    pg.display.flip()
pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using the following code:

```
import pygame as pg
from random import *
import time

pg.init()
scr = pg.display.set_mode((1000,800))
img2 = pg.image.load("asteroid.gif")
img = pg.transform.scale(img2, (75,75))
imgrect = img.get_rect()

#list with asteroid postitions and speeds

xast = []
yast = []
vx = []
vy = []

t = 0.001*pg.time.get_ticks()
tast = t
t0 = t
dtast = 0.5

running = True
while running:
    t = t = 0.001*pg.time.get_ticks()
    dt = t - t0
    if dt >0.:
        t0 = t
        for i in range(len(xast)):
            xast[i] = xast[i] + vx[i] * dt
            yast[i] = yast[i] + vy[i] * dt
    #Create new asteroids every dtast seconds
    if t - tast >= dtast:
        xast.append(999.)
        yast.append(float(randint(0,799)))
        vx.append(-50)
        vy.append(float(randint(-1,1)))
        tast = t

    #Draw frame
    scr.fill((0,0,0))
    for i in range(len(xast)):

        imgrect.center = (xast[i],yast[i])
        scr.blit(img,imgrect)

    pg.display.flip()
pg.quit()
```